# Subsets of a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I produce:

```
("A","b"),("b","C"),("A",),("b",),("C",)
```

from

```
("A","b","C")
```

perhaps itertool can be used put I can't seem to find a function that would suit.

**UPDATE**

Note that **("A","C")** is not in the expected output as I want the subsets to contain members that are consecutive to each other.

Another example:

```
subset(("A","b","C","D"))
```

should yield:

```
("A","b","C"),
("b","C","D"),
("A","b"),
("b","C"),
("C","D"),
("A",),
("b",),
("C",),
("D",)
```

Comment: I don't understand why the result would contain `("A",),("b",),("C",) if you're striving for elements which are consecutive to each other. Perhaps you can better explain the algorithm you're using to decide outputs?

Comment: @VooDooNOFX ("A",), for example, is consecutive with itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
input_tuple = ("A", "b", "C", "d")
output_tuples = []
for subtuple_length in reversed(xrange(1, len(input_tuple))):
    for start_index in xrange(0, (len(input_tuple) + 1 - subtuple_length)):
        output_tuples.append(input_tuple[start_index:start_index + subtuple_length])
```

That builds a list of the consecutive subtuples - you could also `print` them, or `yield` them as a generator or whatever. It's quadratic on the length of the input tuple, but then so is the size of your expected result set so I'm not sure there's a way around that.

Answer (score 5):

There is a rolling window recipe you could use:

```
def window(seq, n=2):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the sequence
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...
    """
    for i in range(len(seq)-n+1):
        yield tuple(seq[i:i+n])

def shrinking_window(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)-1, 0, -1):
        yield from window(seq, i)

print(list(shrinking_window('AbC')))
# [('A', 'b'), ('b', 'C'), ('A',), ('b',), ('C',)]
print(list(shrinking_window('AbCD')))
# [('A', 'b', 'C'), ('b', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'b'), ('b', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('A',), ('b',), ('C',), ('D',)]
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> subset(("A","b","C","D"))
> ```
>
> should yield:
>
> ```
> ("A","b","C"), 
> ("b","C","D"),
> ("A","b"),
> ("b","C"),
> ("C","D"),
> ("A",),
> ("b",),
> ("C",),
> ("D",)
> ```

Sliding windows can be hard. Iteratively shrinking or growing windows are doubly so.

Begin by listing the steps to solve, then create a function that follows those steps:

1. Start at the largest window size (one less than the total length, from the example code).
2. Then calculate the number of windows you need to cover the dataset.
3. Then for each window, you can reuse the number as the starting index, and you need to add the start index to the window size to figure out where each window stops:

The resulting function:

```
def subset(data):
    total_length = len(data)
    for window_length in range(total_length - 1, 0, -1): # biggest first
        n_windows = total_length - window_length + 1
        for each_window in range(n_windows):
            start = each_window
            stop = start + window_length
            yield data[start:stop]
```

Sample data:

```
data = ("A","b","C","D")
```

and now, calling `subset` on `data` returns a generator, which if we pass to `list`, materializes the result:

```
>>> subset(data)
<generator object subset at 0x7fbc3d7f3570>
>>> list(subset(data))
[('A', 'b', 'C'), ('b', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'b'), ('b', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('A',), ('b',), ('C',), ('D',)]
```

#### Deque solution:

I got fascinated by the idea of using deque (from the collections module) for a rolling window and decided to demonstrate this:

```
import collections
import pprint

def shrinking_windows(iterable):
    '''
    Given an ordered iterable (meaningless for unordered ones)
    return a list of tuples representing each possible set
    of consecutive items from the original list. e.g.
    shrinking_windows(['A', 'b', 'c']) returns 
    [('A', 'b', 'c'), ('A', 'b'), ('b', 'c') ...] but not ('A', 'c')
    '''
    window_generator = range(len(iterable), 0, -1)
    results = []
    for window in window_generator:
        d = collections.deque((), maxlen=window)
        for i in iterable:
            d.append(i)
            if len(d) == window:
                results.append(tuple(d))
    return results

pprint.pprint(shrinking_windows('AbCd'))
```

Returns nicely:

```
[('A', 'b', 'C', 'd'),
 ('A', 'b', 'C'),
 ('b', 'C', 'd'),
 ('A', 'b'),
 ('b', 'C'),
 ('C', 'd'),
 ('A',),
 ('b',),
 ('C',),
 ('d',)]
```